# Mui Data Grid Pro v4. Column visibility event is not fired when Show All/Hide All are clicked

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The callback provided by [@mui/x-data-grid-pro](https://mui.com/api/data-grid/data-grid-pro/) for tracking visible columns as far as I can tell is below:

```
onColumnVisibilityChange={(params, event, details) =>
  console.log(params, event, details.api.getVisibleColumns())
}
```

This fires OK when individual columns are toggled however this event doesn't fire on show/hide all button click.

Is there a known workaround for this?

Comment: Facing the same issue. Is there anything changed since that time?

Comment: use onStateChange, it has a param which contains properties to do with any state change like columnReorder, preferencePanel, and columnResize, I added and if statement there to filter out the changes I wanted to track and now it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `onColumnVisibilityChange` callback provides the information only for a single visibility change and is not triggered by bulk visibility changes of show/hide all columns. Since `@mui/x-data-grid-pro v5.3.0`, the grid provides additional callback `onColumnVisibilityModelChange`:

```
onColumnVisibilityModelChange={(params: GridColumnVisibilityModel,  event: MuiEvent<{}>, details: GridCallbackDetails) => {
    console.log(params)
}}
```

The `params` object contains information about visibility of all columns in the table as key-value pairs (`columnName: boolean`). The `onColumnVisibilityModelChange` callback is triggered by both single column and bulk visibility changes. Together with the `columnVisibilityModel` datagrid prop, the callback allows you to control the visibility of the grid's columns:

```
<DataGrid
    columnVisibilityModel={columnVisibilityModel}
    onColumnVisibilityModelChange={newModel => setColumnVisibilityModel(newModel)}
/>
```